# docker ecs command not found

Tags: docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I am trying to use the new `docker ecs` feature, but just get an error `'ecs' is not a docker command`.

Using the latest version of docker edge on macOS 10.15.7

Do I need some additional steps to activate the docker command?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who was following documentation they found about docker ecs written previous to some development changes - while it used to be a plugin, ECS integration is now part of the docker cli itself.

This document covers how to set it up using a context
https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/ecs-integration/